# How to connect a created range to the value of a textarea element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, range

This is how I'm setting the cursor in the first character of a textarea:

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Text</label>
  <textarea ref="inputEl">abc</textarea>
</div>

methods: {
  setInitialCursorPosition () {
    const inputEl = this.$refs.inputEl
    inputEl.focus()
    inputEl.setSelectionRange(0, 1)
  }
},

mounted () {
  this.setInitialCursorPosition()
}
```

I would like to, though share that range between methods. I checked on MDN and they say you can create a range like this:

```
var range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
```

However this only created a range object ... how can I connect this range to my textarea and share this range between methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use a range Object for this when it's simply 2 numbers. A range object is used for something entirely different and is way more complex than what you need or should use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

If you want to share your range between methods simply set an array on your data Object `[0, 1]` or use an Object with a `min` and `max` property if you want something more descriptive.

```
data() {
    return {
        range: {
           min: 0,
           max: 1
        }
    };
}
```

Or simply set an array, either will work.

Comment: My use case for wanting to use a Range object for a textarea value is to use the [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method, so that I can find the x,y coordinates of certain fragments of texts.